# Graph data modeling basics

Tags: data-modeling, orientdb, graph-databases

I am playing around with orientdb quite some time now. In most of my projects I am dealing with GIS and ITS data from traffic networks...so I thought what would be a better datastore for a real world graph than a graph database?

So I wrote a python script to migrate a multimodal traffic network graph from a relational database to orientdb. The basic datamodel (traffic network nodes/crossings and edges/ways) is easy and I also took advantage of orientdbs spatial datatypes to store actually their real world representation. But now it gets hard for me to understand the principles of graph data modeling right.

In real world the nodes/crossings aren't very interesting...most properties are situated on the edges (type of way, lanes, width, etc...). In the graph datamodel the graph is used to associate entities, so the nodes are carrying most of the properties and edges are only to associate nodes with each other.

How would you model a real world traffic network graph in a graph data model the right way, and specifically how would you model aspects like a lane or the coating of a street to the network graphs edge .

P.S. Lanes and Properties of an edge should be their own classes, as they should only be referenced to an network graphs edge, as an edge can carry multiple types of traffic (train, street, walkways, bikeroutes, etc...)

Comment: Type of way, lanes, width are all properties of an object and in a graph database an object is a vertex

Comment: Ok..in our current relational data model also a bike lane (which is an entity on its own with properties for bike relevant aspects like width and pavement) has its own real world representation as it is only derived from the networks edge geometry. So this would be a bike lane vertex which holds an OLineString Property to store the real world representation and is associated to the traffic network edge via an orientdb edge? Is that even possible? Associate an Edge to a Vertex via an Edge? Do I get it right?

Comment: An edge is used to connect two vertices, for example if you have a street and a bike lane,  you could use an edge to connect them. [image here](http://imgur.com/a/Q2lHb)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of graph theory...but the problem is the semantic gap between modelling a real world trafficnetwork graph (crossings are Vertices and streets are edges) and a graph as a data structure where vertices are the carrier of most properties. So how to glue together the street which is modeled as an edge in orientdb to further classes/entities which are modeled as Vertices in orientdb as it is not possible to associate a vertex to an edge via an edge as far as I am aware.

Comment: Somewhat related: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443160/difference-between-data-models/37445719#37445719. Graph databases are a modern reimplementation of the old network data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the following articles, they deal with modeling issues (search google scholar)

Bordoloi, S. and Kalita, B. (2013a). Designing Graph Database Models from existing relational databases. International Journal of Computer Applications, 74(1).

Bordoloi, S. and Kalita, B. (2013b). ER Model to an Abstract Mathematical Model for Database Schema using Reference Graph. International Journal of Engineering Research And Development, e-ISSN, pages 51–60.

De Virgilio, R., Maccioni, A., and Torlone, R. (2014). Model-driven design of graph databases. In Conceptual Modeling, pages 172–185. Springer.

Park, Y., Shankar, M., Park, B.-H., and Ghosh, J. (2014). Graph databases for large-scale healthcare systems: A framework for efficient data management and data services. In Data Engineering Workshops (ICDEW), 2014 IEEE 30th International Conference on, pages 12–19. IEEE.